# Embed sound in flex with variable String

Tags: flex4, embed

I'm looking to do something like:

```
private static const fooDir : String = "foo";
[Embed(source = foo + "/foobar.mp3")]
private var Foo:Class;
```

Flex is only accepting the string if it's written fully out as [Embed(source = "foo/foobar.mp3")]. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't place variables in Embed meta data (Flex 4). Possibly in future versions.

Comment: is this possible in Flex 4.6 yet?